# Trimming the leaves off of an object tree

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have this "tree".

It is a multi-dimensional object. Each "node" has at most two properties, which are `data` and `children`.

Here's an example:

```
{Account: { data: ['stuff'], children: {
  share: {data: ['stuff'], children: {
    share name: {},
    share hold: { data: ['stuff'] }   
  }},
  card: { children: {
    card_access: { data: ['stuff'] } 
  }},
  loan: { children: {
    loan_name: {}
  }}
}}
```

I need to remove any nodes who don't have a `data` attribute *and also* don't have any children with a `data` attribute.

So, the above example would become:

```
{Account: { data: ['stuff'], children: {
  share: {data: ['stuff'], children: {
    share hold: { data: ['stuff'] }   
  }},
  card: { children: {
    card_access: { data: ['stuff'] } 
  }},
}}
```

What is the most concise way to achieve this in JS?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Sounds like a fairly straightforward recursion problem.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Its been giving me issues because of the fact that I cant just ditch a branch If it doesn't have the property, I need to check its children recursively as well. (its like recursion within recursion) My code is becoming verbose and I feel like there's a bunch of different ways to do these types of problems and I could learn from seeing other peoples, likely more concise solutions.

Comment: Huh? Create a function `allEmpty` that checks if a. this object's data is empty and b. this object's children all pass `allEmpty`. `allEmpty` should return a boolean. You have a double recursion here.

Comment: Thats actually what I'm in the process of doing now, it stuck me as I was typing the question, but I still wanted to see others solutions. Ill post mine when I get back into work tomorrow. For now, its quittin' time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
function trimEmpty(obj) {
  for(var o in obj) {
    if(typeof obj[o] === 'object') trimEmpty(obj[o]);
    if(JSON.stringify(obj[o]) === '{}') delete obj[o];
  }
} //trimEmpty

trimEmpty(obj);
```

**Snippet:**

```js
var obj = {
  Account: {
    data: ['stuff'],
    children: {
      share: {
        data: ['stuff'],
        children: {
          share_name: {},
          share_hold: {
            data: ['stuff']
          }
        }
      },
      card: {
        children: {
          card_access: {
            data: ['stuff']
          }
        }
      },
      loan: {
        children: {
          loan_name: {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function trimEmpty(obj) {
  for(var o in obj) {
    if(typeof obj[o] === 'object') trimEmpty(obj[o]);
    if(JSON.stringify(obj[o]) === '{}') delete obj[o];
  }
} //trimEmpty

trimEmpty(obj);
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML= JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Ah! Exactly why I asked this question, I learned a new pattern! Making the recursive call first effectively gives you bottom-up tree traversal.